# Rails: Javascript based on user role

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'd like to know if I am doing this right, or if there's a better way:

In my Rails app, I have pages where, depending on the user who's logged in, certain aspects of the view can change for that page (it's Javascript that handles these changes (i.e. disable checkboxes, etc).

Currently, I have the application.html.erb file add a div to the page labeled with the name of the role. The Javascript checks for which div is active, and executes the Javascript accordingly. I am not too happy with this approach, so I am looking for some alternatives.

I thought about having separate Javascript files, and only including some based on the user role, but that eliminates being able to consolidate all my Javascript into one file in production (doesn't it?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define in your user model a field 'role', for example:

```
class User
  field role

  is_admin?
    role == :admin
  end
end
```

and in your view:

```
<% if current_user.is_admin? %>
  <div class="one-code">
<% else %>
  <div class="two-code">
<% end %>
```

when rails render view, only render one div depending of current_user role.